# Is it possible to edit a deployed Heroku SQLite3 database without redeploying?

Tags: database, sqlite, heroku, terminal

so I'm looking to add some rows into my SQLite3 database but I'd like to just edit the .db file that's currently deployed on Heroku instead of editing my local copy in terminal and then redeploying it...is that possible?